# Account detail link working fine in Sales console but not in Service console

Tags: custom-service-console

I have the following piece of code

<   apex:outputlink value = "/{!Account.Id}" > Account: {!Account.name} < /apex:outputLink>

This link helps me to go back to account detail page in Sales. But when entering into Service console, the link works fine for the first time, when I try this for the second time, it is not working. I have to close the account and open it again.

Can anyone help me in this.